# Datatype decimal(6, 2)

Tags: types

If I have a datatype of decimal(6, 2) what would a sample data be?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC if that makes a difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming you mean that the database type is decimal(6, 2), then this means that your column is set up to store 6 places (scale), with 2 to the right of the decimal (precision). You should treat this as a `decimal` CLR type.

A sample would be `1234.56`.

Comment: Why would a table that stores information on plays that has a row column called 'Target' have this type though?

Comment: Without knowing more about the code model and database schema, I couldn't possibly answer that. Speculation: Could it be a target length for the play? Is it storing hours? 2.25 = 2hr 15min. Just grasping at straws, though.

Comment: Not sure just been given the database for a uni assignment and not sure what it means. There is already a duration column so dont think its that :/ thanks anyways.